# Apache 2 on Mac - localhost requires authentication

Tags: macos, apache, symfony, zend-framework2, localhost

I'm using Apache 2 to run my localhost on Mac (Mavericks), and every time I add a file or a folder in the default directory `/Library/WebServer/Documents` (and its subdirectories) the system asks me to authenticate:[image: system authentication alert]

This is a problem specially when using frameworks like Symfony or Zend Framework because they can't have writing access to folders. What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac/Linux grants access on different levels:

- Per user
- Per group
- Per everybody

The folder `Library/WebServer/Documents` outside of the logged-in user paradigm (you) therefore write access (and other access like execute) is only granted to the administrator of the computer (or so-called `root`) which isn't `you` however on most Mac environment the password of `root` is your password (different users with the same password).

You will want to modify Apache2 configuration and change the directory to a folder located within your user's directory which is something like `/Users/{whatever is your username}` (you will probably need to create the folder).

Once, you moved the content of `/Library/WebServer/Documents` into the new folder, make sure the permission are set properly. Refer to the [following documentation](http://www.macinstruct.com/node/415) at the chapter "How to Modify Permissions with the Info Window".

The reason why your Mac is asking for permissions to write files outside of your user's directory is for security reasons. Imagine if you download a file, execute it and grant access (by giving the root password) then the file could potentially be a virus and erase or do all kind of things on your computer.